# sender is incorrect for dynamically created link buttons

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have code that automatically creates a number of link buttons dynamically and then hooks each of them up to a linkbutton_click event I created. For some reason the "sender" is not correct.

Here's how I created the link buttons...

```
        i = 1
        For Each x As myrecord In x_records
            Dim lb As New linkbutton
            lb.Text = "  " & i.ToString & " "
            lb.Attributes.Add("navigateurl", x.url.ToString)

            AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf lb_Click

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb)
            i += 1
        Next
```

So, as you can see, it creates a bunch of links for paging, such as "  1    2   3   4" etc..... Clicking on 2, for example, will redirect to the proper url.

Here's the click event....

```
    Protected Sub lb_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Response.Redirect(CType(sender, LinkButton).Attributes("navigateurl"))
    End Sub
```

The problem is, when I click on "2" linkbutton, the second link, "3" is the sender in lb_Click. Therefore the redirect url is the one for "3", not "2".

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to se the id property of linkbutton

Comment: @bdn02 when I print out sender ("? sender"), all it shows me is the Text property, which is "  3  ".

Comment: Yes, i have no doubt! I think that the problem maybe that in placeholder there are differents linkbutton and the framework may confuse it. I think that, for test purpose only, you can set the id of all linkbutton at creation time

Comment: @bdn02 Adding the id for each of the linkbuttons solved the issue! Thanks!